# SQL Server: get a percentage using views

Tags: sql, sql-server

The query is: for every product category, percentage of customers buying that product category on Tuesday's over the total number of customers buying that category.

And my attempt is:

```
with temp1 as 
(
    select 
        pc.product_category, 
        count(distinct(s.customer_id)) as customers_tuesdays
    from 
        sales_fact s, product p, product_class pc, customer c, time_by_day t
    where  
        s.customer_id = c.customer_id 
        and s.product_id = p.product_id
        and p.product_class_id = pc.product_class_id 
        and s.time_id = t.time_id
        and t.the_day = 'Tuesday'
    group by 
        pc.product_category
 ),
 temp2 as 
 (
     select 
         pc.product_category, 
         count(distinct(s.customer_id)) as customers_all
     from  
         sales_fact s, product p, product_class pc
     where 
         s.product_id = p.product_id
         and p.product_class_id = pc.product_class_id 
     group by 
         pc.product_category
)
select 
    temp2.product_category, customers_tuesdays/customers_all as ratio
from 
    temp1, temp2
```

The idea is that I have a view for the number of customers that bought in each category on Tuesdays (temp1), another for the number of all customers in each category (temp2), and finally the main query where I calculate the ratio for each category;   I know that the output of each view gives the right results, but the output of the final query is wrong (I get the product categories repeated many times and 0s as ratio). Basically I have a problem in merging the two views to get the ratio. Where is the problem?

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function... Skip those redundant brackets to make code clearer - e.g. simply `count(distinct s.customer_id)`.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). Also, are you really after a Cartesian product in your final statement?

Comment: Why do you think you have a problem?   What data do you have, what result do you expect to get, and what result are you getting instead?

Comment: The relevant data after the join are product_category, the_day, customer_id (it is a fact table).
The output has to be a table of two columns: each row is made with a product category (first column) and the corrisponding ratio asked by the query (second column). Whereas what i get is a column with product categories repeated many times on each rows, and several 0s on the second column.

Answer (score 1):

Well one thing you're doing that would definitely cause this problem is integer division.

In SQL Server, when you divide an integer by an integer, it results in an integer.

Try changing this:

```
customers_tuesdays/customers_all
```

To this:

```
(customers_tuesdays * 1.0)/(customers_all * 1.0)
```